# is it ok to build docker image with docker:18 and load image with different docker:19?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am using circleci to build images and export them as tar.gz using docker version 18.
But now I have docker 19 on all of my swarm manager and worker. 
I have done the following steps to deploy services in swarm.

1. Load docker images using `docker load` command
2. Run `docker stack deploy servername` to deploy

I have tested it, and it works fine but I want to know is it the right thing to do?

Answer (score 0):

It works for sure.

Here is a link with the breaking changes and incompatibilities of docker : 
[Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/breaking_changes/)

When you build a public image, you cannot know the versions of docker which will pulling it, the compatibility is an important thing for the ecosystem of docker.